# Prolog: ID number mapping to a list

Tags: recursion, prolog, counter

I have a variable X that may contain multiple values: X = 1; X = 4; X = 7...

These values map to a list that contain x,y,z, or w. Each one of these value/list pairs are split into multiple facts, so I could have:

```
map(2,[x,y]).
map(3,[x]).
map(9,[y,w]).
```

I'm trying to write a program that, given X, I can look up these lists and count how many occurences of x,y,z, or w there are.

This is my attempt:

```
count(A,B,C,D,X) :- A = 0, B = 0, C = 0, D = 0,
                    check_list(X,x,A), 
                    check_list(X,y,B), 
                    check_list(X,z.C), 
                    check_list(X,w,D).

check_list(X,Element,Counter) :- 
                                 map(X, List),
                                 member(List, Element), 
                                 S is Counter + 1, 
                                 Counter = S.
```

The idea behind my program is I call check_list to check if there is a member that contains x,y,z,w for every possible value of X. If there is that member, I will increment the counter. I then want the values of A,B,C,D to have A = number of occurrences of x, B = number of occurrences of y, etc etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Prolog variables wrong. Variables cannot *change* their values once they are instantiated unless Prolog backtracks to a choice-point previous to the instantiation. For example, in the rule for `count/5` you unify `A` with zero and then you expect that satisfying `check_list(X,x,A)` will bind `A` to the number of occurrences of `x`, but `A` is not a free variable at that point.

So, you have to remove `A = 0, ..., D = 0` from the first rule.

Next, you need a predicate that can be used to find the number of occurrences of an element in a list. You can use `findall/3` for that:

```
occurrences(X, List, N):- findall(_, member(X, List), O), length(O, N).
```

Or you can write it yourself:

```
occurrences(_, [], 0).
occurrences(X, [X|Tail], N):-!, occurrences(X, Tail, N1), N is N1 + 1.
occurrences(X, [_|Tail], N):-occurrences(X, Tail, N).
```